# Two Database Tables with Struts 2.0 Action

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I have trying to save values to two database table with one Struts 2.0 Action class.

I have tried it with Implementing ModelDriven But it didn't catch both VO's. Please give me a solution to catch both VO's in same struts 2.0 action class.

Code Snipper For UserVO.java

```
package com.sajeewi.struts.vo;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserVO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idUser", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int idUser;

    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userVO", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User_DetailsVO user_DetailsVO;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userVO")
    private Set<AccountVO> accountVOs;

    public UserVO() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }   

    public UserVO(int idUser,String username,String password){
        this.idUser = idUser;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }   

    public int getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }
    public void setIdUser(int idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public User_DetailsVO getUser_DetailsVO() {
        return user_DetailsVO;
    }
    public void setUser_DetailsVO(User_DetailsVO user_DetailsVO) {
        this.user_DetailsVO = user_DetailsVO;
    }

    public Set<AccountVO> getAccountVOs() {
        return accountVOs;
    }

    public void setAccountVOs(Set<AccountVO> accountVOs) {
        this.accountVOs = accountVOs;
    }
}
```

This is for User_DetailsVO.java

```
package com.sajeewi.struts.vo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;


@Entity
@Table(name="user_details")
public class User_DetailsVO {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "User_idUser", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "userVO"))   
    private int User_idUser;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private UserVO userVO;

    @Column(name = "contact1", nullable = false, length = 15)
    private String contact1;

    @Column(name = "contact2", nullable = false, length = 15)
    private String contact2;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "add1", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String add1;

    @Column(name = "add2", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String add2;

    @Column(name = "city", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String city;

    public User_DetailsVO() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public User_DetailsVO(UserVO userVO,String contact1,String contact2,String email,String add1,String add2,String city){
        this.userVO = userVO;
        this.contact1 = contact1;
        this.contact2 = contact2;
        this.email = email;
        this.add1= add1;
        this.add2 = add2;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public int getUser_idUser() {
        return User_idUser;
    }

    public void setUser_idUser(int user_idUser) {
        User_idUser = user_idUser;
    }

    public UserVO getUserVO() {
        return userVO;
    }

    public void setUserVO(UserVO userVO) {
        this.userVO = userVO;
    }

    public String getContact1() {
        return contact1;
    }

    public void setContact1(String contact1) {
        this.contact1 = contact1;
    }

    public String getContact2() {
        return contact2;
    }

    public void setContact2(String contact2) {
        this.contact2 = contact2;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAdd1() {
        return add1;
    }

    public void setAdd1(String add1) {
        this.add1 = add1;
    }

    public String getAdd2() {
        return add2;
    }

    public void setAdd2(String add2) {
        this.add2 = add2;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }



}
```

This is the User Action Class

```
package com.sajeewi.struts.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import com.sajeewi.struts.dao.UserDAO;
import com.sajeewi.struts.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl;
import com.sajeewi.struts.vo.UserVO;
import com.sajeewi.struts.vo.User_DetailsVO;

@SuppressWarnings({ "serial" })
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Object>{

    UserVO userVO = new UserVO();
    User_DetailsVO detailsVO = new User_DetailsVO();
    List<UserVO> userList = new ArrayList<UserVO>();
    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAOImpl();


    public List<UserVO> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public void setUserList(List<UserVO> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    public UserDAO getUserDAO() {
        return userDAO;
    }

    public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }   

    public UserVO getUserVO() {
        return userVO;
    }

    public void setUserVO(UserVO userVO) {
        this.userVO = userVO;
    }

    public User_DetailsVO getDetailsVO() {
        return detailsVO;
    }

    public void setDetailsVO(User_DetailsVO detailsVO) {
        this.detailsVO = detailsVO;
    }

    public String addUser(){
//      userDAO.saveUser(this.userVO);
//      userList = null;
//      try {
//          userList = userDAO.searchAllUsers();
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }

        System.out.println(this.userVO);
        System.out.println(this.detailsVO);

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Object getModel() {
        return userVO;

    }




}
```

Jsp View

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>User</title>
</head>
<body>
    <s:div>
        <h2>Registration With Struts 2.0</h2>
        <s:form action="addUser" method="POST">
            <s:div>
                <h4>Enter User Credentials</h4>
                <s:textfield name="username" label="Username"></s:textfield>
                <s:password name="password" label="Password"></s:password>
            </s:div>
            <br>
            <s:textfield name="contact1" label="Contact1 "></s:textfield>
            <s:textfield name="contact2" label="Contact2 "></s:textfield>
            <s:textfield name="email" label="E-Mail "></s:textfield>
            <s:textfield name="add1" label="Address Line 1 "></s:textfield>
            <s:textfield name="add2" label="Address Line 2 "></s:textfield>
            <s:textfield name="city" label="City "></s:textfield>
            <br>
            <s:submit name="Save" value="Save"></s:submit>
        </s:form>
    </s:div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to save to both tables with same form

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you have a separate table to for storing user-info but all that info is being read from single form. In that case, its simple.

Dont go for model-driven as all form-fields are not present in single class else you can have a bean class for the same (I don't recommend it).Populate the corresponding values in the two class objects  `UserVO` and  `User_DetailsVO` using getters n setters in action class.

Now all you do is:

```
Session session = SessionFactory.openSession();
 session.save(userVO);
int savedId = userVO.getIdUser();
 detailsVO. setUser_idUser(savedId);
session.save(detailsVO);
session.close();
```

I am unable to guess in your table which one is primary key and which is foreign key. So save the object which is primary and then save the other object which have FK.

Comment: Hi DarkHouse, I have got solution. Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution. I have changed my JSP like this

Before

```
<s:textfield name="username" label="Username"></s:textfield>
```

Now

```
<s:textfield name="userVO.username" label="Username"></s:textfield>
```

All i have do is add VO name to the textfield name then it automatically catch all the data in the action class for both UserVO and User_DetailsVO

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure... I doubt it will work? as your ModelDriven returns only userVO ... How will User_DetailsVO fields get populated?

Comment: @DarkHorse ModelDriven pushes the model after the action is pushed. If the action wasn't pushed then I18N wouldn't work.

Comment: @DaveNewton I know that but his getModel() returns only userVO object. Do you emphasis that since his action class contains getters & setters for detailsVO, even they get populated?

Comment: @DarkHorse Yes, because the action is on the stack.